# UIScrollView and Animate image view to looks like push up effect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

the new Yahoo! App has an effect when you scroll down, the images looks like being push up slowly. Any idea how this is being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the parallax scrolling effects?

Check out some open soure implementations, for example:

http://maniacdev.com/2013/01/open-source-library-for-adding-a-parallax-scrolling-effect-to-a-stylizable-uitableview/

http://maniacdev.com/2012/11/open-source-ios-control-for-quickly-adding-a-parallax-scrolling-effect-to-your-uiviews/

Comment: What do you mean by link not working? Both links lead to example projects. Check it out again!